# SQL Fetch strings between character or upto end of string

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I'm trying to fetch the string between character two characters and also upto end of string like below

Input:

```
Id=3117;GrpType=UPDATE_116;Status=X
```

Output I need as below:

```
3117
UPDATE_116
X
```

I'm using below query but not fetching exact result

```
SELECT regexp_substr('Id=3117;GrpType=UPDATE_116;Status=X', '.*[^Id=]+') FROM DUAL;

SELECT regexp_substr('Id=3117;GrpType=UPDATE_116;Status=X', '.*[^GrpType=]+') FROM DUAL;

SELECT regexp_substr('Id=3117;GrpType=UPDATE_116;Status=X', '.*[^Status=]+') FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother with regular expressions; `substr` + `instr` do it *nicely*:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Id=3117;GrpType=UPDATE_116;Status=X' from dual)
  3  select substr(col, instr(col, '=', 1, 1) + 1,
  4                     instr(col, ';', 1, 1) - instr(col, '=', 1, 1) - 1
  5               ) id,
  6         substr(col, instr(col, '=', 1, 2) + 1,
  7                     instr(col, ';', 1, 2) - instr(col, '=', 1, 2) - 1
  8               ) GrpType,
  9         substr(col, instr(col, '=', 1, 3) + 1) status
 10  from test;

ID   GRPTYPE    STATUS
---- ---------- ----------
3117 UPDATE_116 X

SQL>
```

Or, regexp:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Id=3117;GrpType=UPDATE_116;Status=X' from dual)
  3  select ltrim(regexp_substr(col, '=\w+', 1, level), '=') result
  4  from test
  5  connect by level <= regexp_count(col, '=');

RESULT
-----------------------------------
3117
UPDATE_116
X

SQL>
```